# Вывод таблицы в элемент GridViev

Tags: c#, winforms

Объясните, пожалуйста, как иcправить ошибку обработчик события не видит orders

Задание. //Задание 2  Создайте приложение по шаблону Windows Forms Application.Поместите на форму элемент управления DataGridView.
//Реализуйте логику, позволяющую выводить общее количество продаж по каждому из сотрудников в элемент управления DataGridView.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HW5._2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet shopDB = new DataSet();
            shopDB.ReadXmlSchema(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDbSchema.xml");
            shopDB.ReadXml(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDBData.xml");
            shopDB.AcceptChanges();
            var orders = shopDB.Tables["Orders"];
            var orderDetails = shopDB.Tables["OrderDetails"];
            orders.Columns.Add("TotalSold", typeof(double), "SUM(Child(Orders_OrderDetails).TotalPrice)");
        }
         private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
          {
               foreach (DataRow order in orders.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OrderId:{0},\nTotalSold:{1}", order["EmployeeID"], order["TotalSold"]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
          }
    }
 }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перенес все в обработчик GridView ошибок нет, но выводв в элемент GridView тоже

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HW5._2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
              
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet shopDB = new DataSet();
            shopDB.ReadXmlSchema(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDbSchema.xml");
            shopDB.ReadXml(@"D:\ADO.NET\DATA\ShopDBData.xml");
            shopDB.AcceptChanges();
            var orders = shopDB.Tables["Orders"];
            var orderDetails = shopDB.Tables["OrderDetails"];
            orders.Columns.Add("TotalSold", typeof(double),       "SUM(Child(Orders_OrderDetails).TotalPrice)");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = orders;
            foreach (DataRow order in orders.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OrderId:{0},\nTotalSold:{1}", order["EmployeeID"], order["TotalSold"]);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Таблицы Orders и Orders_Details связаны. Из первой получаю ID сотрудника из второй сумму по продажам

Comment: Вы объявили _локальную_ переменную `var orders` внутри метода `Form1_Load`. Она не видна снаружи этого метода. Сделайте её _полем_ класса. Тогда она станет доступна во всех методах.

Comment: тагда ShopDB не видит. Если все вынести, то множество ошибок

Comment: Перенес все в обработчик GridView ошибок нет, но вывода в элемент GridView тоже нет. Надо чтобы CustomerID и TotalSold выводило из Orders в GridView

Comment: связал также dataGridView1.DataSource = orders; внутри обработчика, но ничего не дало

Comment: Может в коносоль выводить не надо, но там и просто в GridView выводится

Comment: Думаю выводит надо и в On_Load и в OnClick. Неясно только что и куда